# Magento 2 searchCriteriaBuilder for multiple collection

Tags: magento2, collection

I want to create search functionality for customer to search his invoice order etc.
For this I'm using **searchCriteriaBuilder**  and  **`\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface`**

This collection processor has process method and it works on only one (table) collection.
But I want to implement this search on multiple tables.

Is this possible??

```
 $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);


public function getFilteredList()
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('applied_rule_ids', true, 'null');
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('weight', true, 'null');
        $collection = $this->orderItemRepository->getList(
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
        );
```